# Working properly with snapshot struct in DataSource when Insert\Delete\Update states

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

What is the proper way to use snapshots in dataSource when u want to insert\update\delete cells ?

For example, first way

```
func test() {
    var snapshot = dataSource.snapshot
    snapshot.insert\delete\append
    dataSource.apply(snapshot)
}
```

Second way

```
final class Test {
    var snapshot = Snapshot()

    func test() {
        snapshot.insert\delete\append
        dataSource.apply(snapshot)  
    }
}
```

The last - I have isolated snapshot struct which is not coupled with dataSource. I have tested both but dont see difference between these ways.

Comment: First way, there is no need to keep a strong reference (property) for the snapshot

Comment: I dont understand what u mean, the snapshot is a struct, and we copy it, then we modifying and applying some changes.

Comment: The line `var snapshot = Snapshot()` is pointless because the snapshot is modified locally in `test`. When you apply the snapshot the ownership is transferred to the datasource.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but nevermind, Im curious now about whats the diff) I have removed that line, then.

Comment: There is no difference in terms of execution and performance, there is only a permanent snapshot instance in memory in the second example.